# Regex Replace From Backward

Tags: c#, regex

suppose I had string like below :

```
string signature = "<img src='/Files/A.jpg' />" +
"<img src='http://www.example.net/Files/A.jpg' />" +
"<img src='/Files/A.jpg' />";
```

I want to replace the below string before 'Files' if below phrase is not exits :

```
var url = "http://www.example.net";
```

So the final result would be something like this :

```
string signature = "<img src='http://www.example.net/Files/A.jpg' />" +
"<img src='http://www.example.net/Files/A.jpg' />" +
"<img src='http://www.example.net/Files/A.jpg' />";
```

Note that the second line wouldn't replacing because it has the url. So the code I have wrote is :

```
string signature = "<img src='/Files/A.jpg' />" +
                   "<img src='http://www.example.net/Files/A.jpg' />" +
                   "<img src='/Files/A.jpg' />";
var url = "http://www.example.net";
string pattern = "Files";
Match m = Regex.Match(signature,pattern,RegexOptions.Multiline);


while (m.Success)
{
    int backward = m.Index-url.Length + 6;
    if (backward < 0) backward = 0;
    string fromLastSrc = signature.Substring(backward, m.Index);
    if (!fromLastSrc.Contains(url))
    {
        signature = signature.Insert(m.Index - 1, url);
    }
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

It will find the 'Files' Index and move backwards to check whether url exits before or not. if the url does not exits , it will replace the url before '/Files' , but it breaks with execption below:

```
Index and length must refer to a location within the string
```

Code below won't work , what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion like below,

```
(?<!'http://www\.example\.net)(/Files\b)
```

Then replace the matched characters with `http://www.example.net$1` .

`(?<!'http://www\.example\.net)`
 Negative lookbehind which asserts that the match won't be preceded by `'http://www.example.net`.

[DEMO1](https://regex101.com/r/xC7bJ2/1) [DEMO2](https://regex101.com/r/xC7bJ2/2)

```
string signature = "<img src='/Files/A.jpg' />" +
                   "<img src='http://www.example.net/Files/A.jpg' />" +
                   "<img src='/Files/A.jpg' />";
string result = Regex.Replace(signature, @"(?<!'http://www\.example\.net)(/Files\b)", "http://www.example.net$1");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/vsp1w9)